# Using linq and lambda to filter two collections

Tags: linq, join, filter, lambda

I need to filter a query by two collections.

I have a list of IDs which i need to filter a linq query with

The collection looks like this

```
<table1_id, table2_id>
```

and the contect looks like this

```
idList = <1,10>,<2,12>
```

The query looks like this

```
Dim l = (From t1 In Table1
Join t2 In Table2 ON t1.table1_id Equals t2.table2_id
Where idList.Contains(idList.table1_id) and idlist.Contains(idList.table2_id))
```

Problem is that this works like a cross join so I get all the combinations.

How can make the two collection filter like this query

```
Select * from
table1 t1 Inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
where t1.ID in (1,2)
and t2.ID in (10, 12)
```

Here is the real example from my code:

SQL Query:

```
    Select * from
dbo.v_MARKET_BUSINESS_ROLES mbs
Inner join dbo.SAP_COMPONENT brs
 on mbs.BUSINESS_ROLE_ID = brs.BUSINESS_ROLE_ID
and mbs.erd in ('1','2')
and brs.ID in (10,12)
where 
brs.market_id = 1
```

Code:

Select roles have 2 id's 1 and 2 so Im only collecting the selected roles from a list

```
Dim businessRolesIDs = (From olc In ctx.organization_level_constraint
                                          Where selectedOrgLevels.Contains(olc.organization_level_id) _
                                                            AndAlso olc.market_id = marketId _
                                          AndAlso selectedRoles.Contains(olc.business_role_id)
                                          Select olc.business_role_id, olc.sap_component_id).Distinct.ToList


here I try to filter by the collection returned above

Dim marketBusinessRolesCollection = (From m In ctx.GetMarketBusinessRolesFromView(marketId) _
                                                    Join bs In ctx.business_role_sap_component On m.C_BUSINESS_ROLE_ID Equals bs.business_role_id _
                                                    Where (From item In businessRolesIDs Select item.business_role_id).Contains(m.C_BUSINESS_ROLE_ID)  _
                                                    And (From item2 In businessRolesIDs Select item2.sap_component_id).Contains(bs.sap_component_id)  _
                                                    And bs.market_id = marketId _
                                                    Select New BusinessRole With _
                                                      { 
                                                         .BusinessRoleId = m.ERD
                                                      }).Distinct.ToList
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to see the classes and some data without pseudo code. Btw, is this LINQ to Objects?

Comment: Are you sure about the SQL query? `t1.ID` and `t2.ID` are equalled and the two collections have no common elements, so your SQL query will never show results. If it is correct it would be enough to test whether `t1.ID` is in the intersect of both collections.

Comment: To explain the result I get and what I expect is when I run the sql query I get 2 results because the join is filtering the relationships correctly.  When I run the linq code I get 4 results since it works like a cross join (if Im not mistaken).  In reality I should only get 2 results depending on the query.  if i run the sql statement I get two results from my database.  I will update the post and add some real data...

Comment: Hi Gert, sorry but I might have been missing one small thing when I wrote the pseudo code.  In the where statement they should share a relationship like t1.Market_id = 1 and t2.Market_ID = 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the keys and values of your ID-List.
I understood that this collection is build like a `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`

So your code should look like this

```
Dim l =
    From t1 In Table1
    Join t2 In Table2 ON t1.table1_id Equals t2.table2_id
    Where (From item In idList Select item.Key).Contains(t1.table1_id)
    And (From item In idList Select item.Value).Contains(t2.table2_id);
```

Comment: This gives me the same result as my code above.  Instead of getting two results I get 4 becaues there is no join between the two lists.  Read my comment above with the shared relationship where both share the same market_id.  Its the same in the linq query but I keep getting 4 results but when I run the sql I get 2 results